# Highcharts export: runtime rendering doesn't show rendered table

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm setting chart data dynamically and I've setting a table rendering when chart gets redrawn (I use the redraw event).

```
events: {
            //  load: Highcharts.drawTable,
            redraw: Highcharts.drawTable
},
```

Everything is fine, just when exporting, the rendered table dosen't appear!!

Please check fiddle below:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/slachtar/z9zXM/1344/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a method for drawing a table on load events in additional exportiong options.

```
exporting: {        
    filename: 'Par_Type_' + new Date().getDate() + "_" + (new Date().getMonth()+1) + "_" + new Date().getFullYear(),
    fallbackToExportServer: false,
    chartOptions: {
        chart: {
            events: {
               load: Highcharts.drawTable
          }
        }
      }
            },
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/z9zXM/1345/